# Build - Error: Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: build

I am trying to run!
The test works without a problem on Windows
It fails when it tries to install the system dependencies where it gives me the error ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
Any ideas? Many thanks!

Screenshot

[enter image des[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3x3Y.png)cription here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFQD5.png)

.github/workflows/python-app.yml